# Удаление записи в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу удалить запись которую задаст пользователь по id, но не получается.

форма :

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
      Введите номер для редактирования
      <input type="text" name="clearid" size="3"/> 
      Ввеедите новый номер
      <input type="text" name="newphone" size="3"> <br> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="ed" value="Изменить"> <br> <br>
      Введите номер для удаления
      <input type="text" name="clear" size="3"/> 
      <input type="submit" name="del" value="удалить">
    </form>
```

php код:

```
   if (isset($_POST['del']))  //удаление
    {
        $chek_query = " DELETE FROM number WHERE id='$clear'";
        $db = mysqli_query ($connect, $chek_query) or die("Ошибка" .mysqli_error($connect)); // подключение к таблице
        if ($db)
            {
                echo" Запись удалена ";
            }
            mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```

если в $chek_query = " DELETE FROM number WHERE id='$clear'";   указать вместо $clear  номер id в коде, то он удаляет. редактирование работает нормально.

опись переменных:

```
      $newphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['newphone']);
      $clearid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['clearid']);
      $clear = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['clear']);
```

Comment: Попробуйте закончить запрос вот так `WHERE id=".$clear;` У вас ведь двойные кавычки

Comment: может просто вывести запрос `exit($chek_query);` строкой ниже объявления (сразу перед отправкой в бд) и посмотреть что там получается в итоге?

Comment: @stckvrw забыли одинарные кавычки (получается sql-inj) + там и так двойные и переменную можно подставить как он и написал в вопросе

Comment: Не получается - завершается ошибкой или SQL-запрос отрабатывает корректно, но ничего не происходит в базе?

Answer (score 1):

Все я разобрался, всем спасибо, нужно было $clear описать в условии 
if (isset($_POST['del']))  //удаление

Answer (score 0):

```
$chek_query = "DELETE FROM number WHERE id='".$clear."'";
```

Попробуй так. Должно работать.